# How to add action to one dynamic button in one UIView Control to move back to UIViewController

Tags: iphone

In my application, i am using UIViewController and dynamically created UIView.In that view dynamically created subviews(UIButton and PickerViewController)..I want to display selected picker view value in a label control in UIViewController... How to add action to this button to move back to UIViewController...

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the reference of the UIViewCOntroller to the subview or you can create delegate methods for the subview.

Method 1 :

//below code is written in your UIViewController

/*You should write the implementation of initWithFrame:viewController: in UIVIEW

```
CustomUIView *youSubView = [[CustomUIView alloc]initWithFrame : yourFrame viewController:self];

//below code is in CustomUIView

- (id) initWithFrame :(CGRect)frame viewController:(id)vc
{
....
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:vc action:methodinVc forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

}
```

Method 2 :

Make protocol and delegate in UIView and make the UIViewController to respond to the delegate calls